# Serving contextual based ads on sites built entirely in Flash?

Tags: flash, adsense, ads

What's the status of adsense (or equivalent) being able to serve contextual based ads on sites built entirely in Flash?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Mochiads](https://www.mochiads.com/). Adsense ish type of service for embedding into Flash applications.

(they're behind [mochiweb](http://code.google.com/p/mochiweb/), the erlang web server, which is way cool)

Comment: nice, will probably actually use them. What about a company similar to adsense that places context based ads on sites that are built in flash